# retornar resultado de una funcion asincrona en javascript

Tags: javascript, async

tengo la siguiente función, que es una consulta en una base de datos. Me gustaría que al llamar a la función principal `count` me devolviese como retorno el valor de `row[key]` que ahora mismo lo saco en la consola y veo su valor perfectamente, el problema es que si pongo un `return` e intento obtener su valor al hacer la llamada siempre me devuelve un `undefined`, ¿Que debo hacer para obtener el retorno correctamente?

```
export function count(nameColumn, value) {
  (async function() {
  try{
  let connectionstring = "Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server; Server=DESKTOP-L7VRKM6\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=PCIm213221;trusted_connection=yes;";
  let conn = await HMIRuntime.Database.CreateConnection(connectionstring);
  let query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Recipe WHERE " + nameColumn + "='" + value + "'";  
  let results = await conn.Execute(query);
  if(results !== undefined && results !== null)
  {
    let statements = results.Results;
    for(let statement in statements)
    {
      let rows = statements[statement].Rows;
      for (let i in rows)
      {
        let row = rows[i];
        for(let key in row)
        {
           Console.log(row[key]));            
        }
      }
    }
  }
conn.Close();
}
catch(e)
{
  let res = e.Results;
  for(let statement in res)
  {
    let errors = res[statement].Errors;
    for (let i in errors)
      {
        let detailed = errors[i];

        Console.log(-1);
      }
    }
  }
 })();
}
```

Comment: El porqué es simple: *es un proceso asíncrono, y no se puede obtener el resultado de un proceso asíncrono inmediatamente*.

Comment: Si necesitas el valor inmediatamente, por qué declaras la función como `async`  en primer lugar. Me parece que no debieras hacerlo, pues estas pidiendo que funcione como una función sincrona.

Comment: @jachguate es un snippet de una consulta ODBC en una base de datos, directamente lo construye como asíncrono y el resultado lo saca por consola pero mi intención era utilizar el retorno para gestionarlo a mi manera, no estoy en una aplicación de consola y quiero conocer el resultado para hacer una cosa u otra.

Comment: @Edulon es imposible sacar el resultado directamente de una funcion asincrona, ya que esta siempre retorna una `Promise` asi le digas o no que retorne algo, por lo tanto lo unico que debes hacer es usar los metodos `.then` y `.catch` donde requieras usar esa informacion, dentro de `.then` estaria el resultado que esperas y solo ahi adentro estaria disponible, ademas no puedes pensar en asignar valores asincronos a una variables, simplemente no lo intentes no va a pasar, en su lugar no deberias crear esas variables que contengan esa informacion, sino directamente usar la promise.

Comment: En resumen, tu informacion siempre estara atrapada en una promise y no hay forma de sacarla, asi que debes usar obligatoriamente `.then` y `.catch`, esto es una de las desventajas del codigo asincrono en javascript, que estaras peleando con promises, pero luego que las dominas ya sabes que cosas puedes hacer y que no. recuerda NO puedes asignar valores asincronos a una variable, ya que por ser asincronos cuando intentes usarlas estaran indefinidas, la solucion por ende es la que he dicho arriba.